# A violation of the Maximum Work Theorem?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, entropy, heat-engine

Consider the PV diagram I've drawn at the end of this post. Consider the processes drawn thereon: (1-2-3) is an isobaric step followed by an isochoric step, while (1-3) is an adiabatic expansion (I couldn't figure out how to flip the arrow, but NB that I am not interested in discussing a cycle here and (1-3) is meant to be interpreted as going from 1 to 3).

My question is as follows. I recently learned (Callen Chapter 4.5) about the maximum work theorem, which gives the maximum work that can be extracted from a given system in taking it between two specified states, while there is access to some fixed "reversible heat source" (RHS) and fixed " reversible work source" (RWS) (on which the work is done). It was proven -- and I agree with the proof naturally -- that the maximum such work obtains from a reversible $\Delta S_{tot} = 0$ process with respect to the overall, composite system of three subsystems.

Now in this specific case, fix the RHS and RWS. The adiabatic process (1-3) is clearly reversible, since it is quasistatic and since there is no heat transfer. Thus, by the theorem, it must supply the maximum work in going between the two states. But the process (1-2-3) evidently supplies more work (area under the PV diagram), so where am I going wrong? Obviously, one of the hypotheses entering the maximum work theorem must be violated, but I can't imagine which one.

**Edit:** I believe the correct resolution is to note that, in fact, both lead to precisely the same work done by a RWS (as they must by the MWT); this fact is obscured in this particular case by the fact that the \emph{direct work} done in the given reversible path. That is, the difference in area between the two paths corresponds to different values of $W$ in the process, but we note again that $W \neq -W_{RHS}$ in general; instead, we have $Q + W = -Q_{RHS} - W_{RWS}$ and so $W_a \neq W_b$ does not at all contradict the possibility that $W_b + Q_b + Q_{RHS,b} = -W_{RWS,b} =  - W_{RWS,a} = W_a + Q_a + Q_{RHS,a}.$

[image]

Comment: To whoever downvoted and voted that it needs more clarity, can you help me by stating what it is that needs clarifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are just mistaking what the theorem is saying. Along isentropic path 1->3 you have no entropy / heat transfer, and thus the maximum work is whatever you get. Along path 1->2->3 there would be a need for infinitely many heat pads of different temperatures, from which you absorbed some heat. That heat is being converted to work, and that is why the limit of maximum work along path 1->2->3 is a little greater than that of path 1->3 isentropically.

Comment: So you are saying that the resolution is that there does not exist a (single) RHS such that (1-2-3) is followed?

Comment: In the path 1->3 you did not even use the RHS. The resolution is really that you needed to understand that the theorem is really saying that reversible processes allow you to get the most work out of the accessible set of stuff you have.

Comment: I understand that the 1-3 path does not use a RHS, but in comparing it to 1-2-3 we can take it "as if" it had the RHS we are associating with 1-2-3. So the only way out here is to say that there cannot exist said RHS to take us along 1-2-3?

Comment: Well, as I told you earlier, 1-2-3 has many RHS, not just one, but otherwise is perfectly fine under the theorem. Because you absorbed some heat from any of the RHS, so the maximum work is a little bigger under 1-2-3 than via 1-3

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm beginning to understand. But how do we *prove* that many RHS are required?

Comment: Easy; if you look in TS space and realise that you have something that is not just two isothermal processes bounded by isentropic processes, e.g. you have any other process than those two types, then you have essentially infinitely many RHS, each one being an isothermal heat pad.

Comment: OK, I think I am getting close to understanding. Let me spell everything out for my own benefit, and please advise if I'm missing something.  We can consider the system in terms of (P,V,N) coordinates or in terms of (T,S,N) coordinates (N is a spectator variable naturally). From the PVN picture, it's clear that in the course of 1-2-3, we move to a point of different S (since we are moving off the initial adiabat/isentrope).  We eventually return to that adiabat at the end though, which is to say we return to the same $S$. But how can I see that we are not at the same temperature while doing...

Comment: ...this? Why can't we move in TS space at constant temperature while respecting the requirements I outline above? I guess there's a sense in which we argue that if we go back along the same isotherm in TS space to the initial entropy, then we are returning to states which we were at previously, but that would contradict what we are seeing in the PV plane?

Comment: isentropes and isotherms are not horizontal and vertical lines on PV diagram, so even just visually we can know that those require a lot of different heat pads

Comment: I agree, but I am talking about a general proof for an arbitrary system so I'm hoping to justify things more rigorously.

Comment: You can make that argument rigorous.

Comment: I certainly tried to above! I'm just hoping you can help me figure out the part I mentioned: "I guess there's a sense in which we argue that if we go back along the same isotherm in TS space to the initial entropy, then we are returning to states which we were at previously, but that would contradict what we are seeing in the PV plane?". Does that seem like a reasonable way to argue that the final state (3) has a different temperature than the initial state (1)? If so, then it would remain for me to show that there cannot exist a RHS  which at all times matches this temperature.

Comment: I do not understand what you are talking about. You said that path 1-3 is an isentrope, and isentropes always change temperature. That is, the 4 simple reversible processes, isobar, isovolumetric, isentrope and isothermal, appear manifestly different in either of the pV diagram or TS diagram, although it would take some help to separate isentropes from isotherms on the pV diagram, say. There should thus never be confusion in this part of the understanding of thermodynamics.

Comment: OK, I think I am beginning to understand. I think the last part of the proof of the original question that I need is that there cannot exist a RHS which supplies heat reversibly as the temperature is varying. Why is this? If the RHS is a reservoir I can see this since then the reservoir and system must at some point be at different temperatures. If the RHS is not a reservoir (finite heat capacity), why can't it's temperature change with that of the system? Is the answer that the temperatures would need to change in different directions so that eventually you'd have a nonzero $T$ gradient?

Comment: Every single RHS has to have a fixed temperature, hence why I kept calling them thermal heat pads (following Feynman's naming). It cannot be finite because you are taking heat from one side to the other, so one side is always attempting to change temperatures opposite the the other, and thus if they were originally at one temperature at the start, they will quickly move out of sync in temperature if you want to play this game.

Comment: You could have considered a dynamical system as your heat reservoir, but then it would be incredibly hairy to deal with the irreversible entropy generation in the universe from having such a dynamical system.

Comment: I think you might want to move to chatrooms for all these long chats we are having. The h bar chatroom is quite lively and helpful

Comment: "they will quickly move out of sync in temperature if you want to play this game", I think this gets me to my answer, thank you! I am not sure how to access these chat rooms though?

Comment: I have thought about this more and have come to the conclusion that in fact both lead to the same amount of reversible work done by the RWS ($W_{RWS}$), but along the 1-2-3 path there is also some heat transfer (hence why the "direct work" done $W$ is different).

Comment: I just made an edit here -- can I ask if you think it's correct?

Comment: I think it is easier to just say that the maximum reversible work done is _relative to a specific amount of heat exchange._

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? At any rate, Callen's discussion is more general than conversion of heat to work; it talks about the change of state between any two states for a given (primary) (sub)system. And does my edited statement sound correct, even if you don't like the phrasing? Sorry, I have just really been trying to understand this Callen chapter for a while.

Comment: I know; but I think it is impossible to understand what Callen is saying unless we take into account that between any two equilibrium states, a path can be driven like a heat engine and produce any bigger amount of reversible work by converting heat to work. I do not know enough to evaluate if your edited statement is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Callen's theorem does not cover this problem because the setup in Section 4.6 assumes a single thermal reservoir at a fixed temperature $T_{RHS}$, and similarly the work reservoir(s) is(are) also fixed at its(their) respective potential(s). None of these stages is possible reversibly while both reservoirs are connected because the thermal equation of state $pV=RT$ will make sure that in stage $1 \to 2$ the temperature must vary, while in stage $2 \to 3$ we already know the pressure must vary. Neither of them is allowed if the process be reversible *and* connected to *these* reservoirs and to nothing else, by nothing else I mean a Carnot engine that can absorb/dump its entropy at variable temperatures or pressures. And of course in the adiabatic (isentropic) stage the cylinder cannot be connected to the the entropy source because during its transformation the gas temperature will change and their will be entropy exchange between them.

You cannot just take the contour integral and declare that it is equal to your work output unless the process is reversible.

Comment: To reiterate a question asked in the other answer, am I understanding in that you are saying that the resolution is that there does not exist a (single) RHS such that (1-2-3) is followed? I should add that Callen does not assume a single thermal reservoir in general; he assumes a reversible heat source (one single auxiliary system) which, in the large heat capacity limit, becomes a reservoir. Of course, that does not change things materially. I also want to add that it seems you are assuming an ideal gas for the primary subsystem, but why? That is not to be assumed here in general I believe.

Comment: So, effectively, it's not clear to me how we argue that the temperature drops for an arbitrary system in this process?

Comment: You are right, it does not have to be an ideal gas just to have some well defined thermal and caloric equations of state, such as, say, $f(T, p, V)=0$ and $g(S, p, V)=0$. The heat capacities are positive, so the temperature is monotonically increasing function of entropy and of internal energy for a fixed volume or for fixed pressure.  If the system *does* work as in $1\to 2$ and is not connected to a thermal reservoir, then it must reduce its internal energy, hence the decrease of its temperature. A work-free expansion of an ideal gas is isothermal, but that is an irreversible expansion.

Comment: Yes, that is my point "there does not exist a (single) RHS such that (1-2-3) is followed" because it cannot be done reversibly, and your plot implies reversibility. And this is what @naturallyInconsistent is saying with  "a need for infinitely many heat pads of different temperatures". By my reading (not recently and it could be wrong), Callen assumes that these two reservoirs (large sources) are connected to the system all the way through. If that is the correct reading then either your path is irreversible or to make it reversible you need an infinity of sources or Carnot engines.

Comment: As I recall reading Callen many many years ago I also found that chapter particularly confusing and not very enlightening.

Comment: Got it (I think), thank you! I think there are many subtleties I am missing but hopefully one day I will figure it out.

Comment: I just made an edit here -- can I ask if you think it's correct?